# How to decompose a monotone polygon into two monotone chains

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, polygon, triangulation

I'm trying to triangulate a monotone polygone. The algorithm requires to represent the polygone like 2 monotone chains. There is no description, how to do it. Is there any simple algorithm, which allows to decompose a monotone polygone into 2 y-monotone chains?

Answer (score 1):

If your polygon is monotone **with respect to Y-axis** any horizontal line intersects polygon at most two times), then just get two vertices with max and min Y-values. Left and right polylines connecting these extremal vertices are Y-monotone chains.
[image]